# Simplest concurrent loop with bounded concurrency

Tags: go

I'm looking for the simplest code for looping over a dataset in parallel. The requirements are that the number of goroutines is fixed and that they can return an error code. The following is a quick attempt which doesn't work, since the loops will deadlock as both goroutines are blocking on the error channel

```
package main

import (
        "fmt"
        "sync"
)


func worker(wg *sync.WaitGroup, intChan chan int, errChan chan error) {
        defer wg.Done()

        for i := range intChan {
                fmt.Printf("Got %d\n", i)
                errChan <- nil
        }
}

func main() {
        ints := []int{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10}

        intChan := make(chan int)
        errChan := make(chan error)
        wg := new(sync.WaitGroup)

        for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
                wg.Add(1)
                go worker(wg, intChan, errChan)
        }

        for i := range ints {
                intChan <- i
        }

        for range ints {
                err := <- errChan
                fmt.Printf("Error: %v\n", err)
        }

        close(intChan)
        wg.Wait()
}
```

What is the simplest pattern for doing this?

Comment: Either separate routines reading `intChan` and `errChan`, or more likely, one channel on which you send structs containing both the `int` and the `error`.

Answer (score 0):

Listen for errors in a goroutine:

```
go func() {
  for err:=range errChan {
    // Deal with err
  }
}()

for i := 0; i < 2; i++ {
    wg.Add(1)
    go worker(wg, intChan, errChan)
}

for i := range ints {
  intChan <- i
}
close(errChan) // Error listener goroutine terminates after this
```